# Show divs inline in cart page woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to show the two boxes in my cart page next to each other. The cart summary and the cart totals.

[image: Picture of the boxes]

I tried giving different widths to each class but I can't get it right.

Also tried displaying inline but nothing  happens.

I will  leave a link to a [product page](https://test1.wpdevcloud.com/pulsera/p1/) so you can add it to cart and you'll be redirected to the cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrDRF.png

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .woocommerce-cart form.woocommerce-cart-form, .cart-collaterals {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 49% !important;
        width: calc(50% - 2px) !important;
    }

    .woocommerce-cart .cart_totals {
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-left: 1px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Beneris. How can I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution could look like this:

```
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="https://test1.wpdevcloud.com/carrito/" method="post" 
    style="width: 66%; float: left;">
... 
</form>
```

```
<div class="cart-collaterals" style="width: 33%;float: left;">
    <div class="cart_totals " style="width: 100%;">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: site]

This could be done more nicely with flexbox etc. but would require more edits.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can use flexbox, just replace below code

```
.woocommerce-cart form.woocommerce-cart-form, .cart-collaterals {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 49% !important;
    width: calc(50% - 2px) !important;
}
```

with

```
.woocommerce{
    display: flex;
}

.woocommerce-cart .woocommerce-cart-form {
    width: 60% !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.cart-collaterals {
    width: 40% !important;
}
```

flex box is very easy to use.